# Prevent SSL for addon domains

Tags: redirect, ssl, add-on

I'm sure someone would have asked this question earlier, but i wasnt able to find a correct answer yet.

I have a primary domain www.domain.com and 2 addon domains www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com, all these were working fine till when I installed a SSL for the primary domain.

I have a redirect .htaccess as follows

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

With this, i see the addon domain URL's as follows

https://www.domain.com/domain1/ or /domain2/

Can anyone please guide me on how to get back to

www.domain1.com for my addons..?

your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Abilash

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable SSL on my addon domain by putting the following code to the end of the .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(home|help)(.*)/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

And it worked!